# Regular Exp to read lines that starts with exact word

Tags: php, regex

I need to read line that starts with word "TEMP", to do so I have written as:

```
$Temp_line= preg_grep('/^[\s]*TEMP[^\r\n]*/m', $data);

print_r($Temp_line);
```

prints output as:

> "Array ( [53] => TEMP 650.0 ! Temperature (K) [131] => TEMPERATURE 650.0000 K [899] => TEMPERATURE 2541.0376 K ) "

But I want to read only:

> "Array ( [53] => TEMP 650.0 ! Temperature (K)"

How to write pattern using preg_match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match a widespace character (`\s`) after `TEMP`:

```
$Temp_line= preg_grep('/^\s*TEMP\s[^\r\n]*/m', $data)
```

Comment: @Naveena this will not match `TEMP`

Comment: @hek you don't need to put `\s` inside character class. Just `\s*` would be fine.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes if line is only `TEMP`

Comment: @vks Your regex fails here `TEMP,CELCIUS`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for the hint! :) I just copied `[\s]` from the question without having a closer look. Sure, the character class isn't required here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : There is space at the beginning of the line so i added [\s]. The text line starts with TEMP but there is space at beginning of line.

Comment: @Naveena It's not about the space exists or not. It's just a hint . You don't need to add that space character inside a character class. `[\s]=\s`

Comment: @AAvinash Raj :thanks for that nice information. I am working for the first time on these kind of expression. hope i will learn soon

Answer (score 4):

```
^\s*\bTEMP\b[^\r\n]*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/11

Comment: What's the need for `\b` before `TEMP`?

Comment: The question is flawed without sample input. Imho nonsensical attaching `[^\r\n]*` with `preg_grep()` which returns only array items matching the pattern. Plus for the `\b`

Comment: @Jonny5 yeah actually just modified OP's regex.didnt dig into it :P